# Get only changed components in a clone command in git

Tags: git

I am trying to set up a continuous integration using Jenkins and Git which seems to be a typical scenario - My aim is to read the changes from Git and deploy it to a target Salesforce org using ANT - the deployment part seems to be fine as I am able to call ANT scripts easily.

But if I do a complete clone of my Git branch, all components (not only the changed ones) are coming as part of the clone - this is kind of frustrating as when ANT tries to deploy, it takes the entire folder and not just the components mentioned in package.xml.

I wanted to know if there is a command which would allow me to clone only the changed components by comparing it with the parent branch.

E.g. I have the following hierarchy: `master -> release_branch -> feature_branch`.

I make changes in feature_branch and merge to the release_branch. Now I want to compare release_branch and master and get only the changed components as part of a clone command.

Just for information, my package.xml is something that I am planning to have changed in git itself, so that it's easier to run ANT on the local cloned folder (hope this helps!).

Below are commands I tried, but I am unsure of the order in which these should be executed (if in case these are correct):

## below command is to clone the specific branch - works fine

```
git clone --single-branch --branch release1_develop https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>
```

But the above command gives all the components, whereas I want only the changed one.

Comment: Why are you doing a clone and not a pull / fetch?

Comment: The idea is to delete the local folder each time and do a clone again as when i use ANT, it pushes the entire folder - hence I need only relevant components to be pulled in (along with their folder structure) - if there is a way to do a pull and delete all other components which are not part of the pull, I am open for that idea as well!